# DNS Scavenging on Enterprise Environment

Tags: active-directory, internal-dns

About DNS Scavenging in Microsoft Active Directory internal DNS server, why does by default it is not enabled? how do you usually implement this scavenging system on your enterprise? (what to look out for)

I was running WinSvr2008R2 since 2014 and currently migrating to Functional Level of WinSvr2016, when noticing that there are too many old DNS records not clearing, and was just starting to read about DNS Scavenging,

Thank you for any advice,

Answer (score 0):

> why [..] by default [..] not enabled?

Because it deletes data.

> how do you usually implement this

There a many different strategies; usually around 7 days is a good starting point - but this depends on your domain and it's usage.

Comment: Thank you for that enlightment, so 7 days is a good start point before deleting the records, any other thing I need to watch out for before applying this method?

Comment: A lot. This https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21724.how-dns-aging-and-scavenging-works.aspx may be a good start.